# How to get JWT token from URL using Express server?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, json-web-token

Supposing the URL is like `http://localhost:3000/auth?token=helloworld`

How to get the jwt token from this url using express server? I have tried this code below.. no output.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

    router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var token = req.query.token;
    console.log(token);
    try {
        var decoded = jwt.verify(token, 'thisismysecretstring');
        console.log(decoded);
        res.send(req.query.token);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});

app.use('/auth', router);
```

Comment: If that code doesn't yield any output (assuming that you also have an `app.listen(3000)` in there somewhere), there's something else going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL format should be like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/auth/?token=helloworld
```

Now, it is working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try that

```
var express = require('express');
var validate = require('../../validate');
var service = require('./loginService');
var router = express.Router();

router.route('/authenticate').post(service.ldap, function(req, res, next) {
    var parameters = req.body;
    parameters.bluepages = req.bluepages;

    service.login(parameters).then(function(body) {
        res.status(200).json(body);
    }).fail(function(err) {
        res.status(err.status).json(err.data);
    });
});
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with JWT's.